# Python flask directory structure for service layer?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, flask

I'm an aspnet core developer and trying to do a test project in python using the flask framework. But because of my lack of understanding of the structure of python projects I'm having hard time compiling it. I don't understand why does it care if I keep my python file in another directory. In C# you can access all classes inside the same namespace without importing anything.

Here's my python flask project structure looks like. I can't seem to work it with this way. I'm trying to import my **home_service.py** inside **home.py** file where home **routes** are present (`in aspnet's term controller`) and the logger doesn't seem to be accessible either.
And **home_service.py** can't import **db_util.py** either.

Would any python flask expert please guide me in the right direction?

```
/../../Projects/flask-test-project
├── test-project/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── static/
│       └── site.css
│   ├── templates/
│   │   ├── layout.html
│   │   ├── home.html
│   │   ├── offerings.html
│   │   ├── login.html
│   │   ├── register.html
│   │   ├── 404.html
│   │   ├── 500.html 
│   ├── views/
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── home.py
│   │   ├── offerings.py
│   │   ├── login.py
│   │   ├── register.py
│   ├── service/
│   │   ├── home_service.py
│   │   ├── db_util.py
├── flask-venv-for-ubuntu/
├── requirements.txt
└── run.py

**run.py**
from test-project import app
from datetime import datetime
import logging

todays_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')
logging.basicConfig(filename='error'+ todays_date+'.log',level=logging.Trace)
app.run(debug=True)
app.logger.trace(“Inside run.py”)


**__init__.py**
from flask import g, Blueprint, request
from psycopg2

# $ pip install sentry-sdk[flask]
from werkzeug.exceptions import HTTPException 

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(error):
    return render_template('404.html')

@app.errorhandler(HTTPException)
def handle_exception(e):
    app.logger.error(e)
    return render_template(“500.html”)

@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_connection():
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is not None:
        db.close()

from test-project.views import home
from test-project.views import login
from test-project.views import register
from test-project.views import offerings
app.register_blueprint(home.mod)
app.register_blueprint(login.mod)
app.register_blueprint(register.mod)
app.register_blueprint(offerings.mod)

**db_util.py**
from flask import g
import psycopg2 

POSTGRES_CONNECTIONSTRING = “……...”

def get_db():
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is None:
        db = g._database = psycopg2.connect(POSTGRES_CONNECTIONSTRING)
    return db

def query_db(query, args=(), one=False):
   try:
     cur = get_db().execute(query, args)
     rv = cur.fetchall()
     cur.close()
     return (rv[0] if rv else None) if one else rv   
   finally:
    if(cur)
       cur.close()

**home_service.py**
import db_util

def get_something
   app.logger.Debug(“get_something started”)
   return query_db(“select count(*) as myCount from table1;”)


**home.py**
import home_service

mod = Flask(“home”,__name__)

@mod.route(“/something”)
def something():
   app.logger.Debug(“get_something started”)
   return render_template(“home.html”, count_of_table1=get_something().myCount)
```

*Please don't recommend me to use SQLAlchemy or any other orm. I want to do it my way. Thanks!*

Comment: For starters, you are missing an __init__.py file in the service directory.

Comment: Thank @Jeremy for guiding me into the right direction. I added empty `__init__.py` in the service folder and full namespace when importing. 

For example to import `db_util` into `home_service.py`---
`import test-project.service.db_util` and it worked.